# Cannot understand jenkins deployment error

Tags: jenkins, deployment, dependency-management, ant

I am new to jenkins, and i am trying to make a deployment into a remote serve, but i am getting the following error:

```
    Current dependency:com.vmd positionWatchLoader latest.integration
:: loading settings :: file = /tmp/tmp.uhKXp22892/ivysettings.xml
:: resolving dependencies :: com.org#appli-caller;working
    confs: [default]
    found com.org#appli;300000 in local
    [300000] com.org#appli;latest.integration
:: resolution report :: resolve 82ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   1   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.org#appli;300000: configuration not found in com.org#appli;300000: 'runtime'. It was required from com.org#appli-caller;working default

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

And i am not able to interpret the error message, it says:  `configuration not found in com.vmd#positionWatchLoader;300000` which configuration ??

```
It was required from com.vmd#positionWatchLoader-caller;working default
```

I have no dependency called: com.vmd#positionWatchLoader-caller !!!!!

I do not know if it can help: i am using Ant to build and Ivy to manage dependencies.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: This is clearly a dependency error. Instead of using ant as the build tool, is there any reason you have not migrated to maven or gradle? There is a lot better dependency management. Plus, if you use Eclipse or so, it should be easy to convert the project into a maven based within minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem publishing the ivy.xml file to nexus too, adding `publishivy="true"` to my publishing task in my build.xml file.